# How to make a "set mute role" command in Discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I know the question kinda sounds vague, but hear me out!

I'm already aware on how to create a mute command, however as I'm planning to release my Discord bot to the public, I'm stuck on one question: How do I make a command that sets the mute role?
Basically, every mute role has different IDs. And basically I want it so that if the person says "?setmuterole {role id}" it'll set the mute role for the server.

Problem is, I'm not sure how to do that.
Can someone help me? I've tried so many times but ultimately failed.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the data in a file, for example a json file:

```py
@client.command #could be bot.command for you or something else
async def set_mute_role(ctx, role_id:int):
    json_file = open("your_json_file.json", "r") #open the json file you have to create before running this 
    role_ids = json.load(json_file) #load the json to a dict
    role_ids[ctx.guild.id] = role_id #add the role id to the dict
    json_file.close()
    json_file = open("your_json_file.json", "w")
    json.dump(role_ids, json_file) #save the dict as json file
    json_file.close() #close the json file again
```

And in your mute command get the role id via:

```py
json_file = open("your_json_file.json", "r")
role_ids = json.load(json_file)
role_id_to_mute = role_ids[ctx.guild.id]
json_file.close()
```